# отформатировать и вывести timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой вывода даты. В базе данных в таблице files есть столбец date формата timestamp. В нем значение 2017-07-20 09:32:23

Когда делаю выборку

`$sql = "SELECT * from files where id= $i"; // $i итерационная переменная
     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
     $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $date=date('F/j/Y',strtotime($result['date']));`

И вывожу на экран `echo "<p>Дата:'$date'</p>";`

Выводит 'January/1/1970'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся? Может, подскажете как правильно отформатировать timestamp, чтобы он отображал точное время залива файла на сервер? Когда пробовал `$date=$result['date'];`, echo вообще ничего не выводил кроме ковычек. Также экспериментировал с sql запросом: id =1, SELECT * - ничего не помогло.

Пользовался [Описанием функции date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: Форматируйте дату на стороне MySQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Проверьте, точно ли здесь `$result['date']` та дата которая вам нужна

Comment: Воспользовался  $sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%W %M %e %Y") FROM files'; но не помгло

Comment: В массиве result почему-то пусто  при любом запросе.. Хотя бы понятно почему он просто кавычку выводит вместо даты.

Comment: и плюс проверте не пустое ли значения в базе

Comment: В базе 2 записи:
1
123455.jpg
abrgpro
NULL
2017-07-20 09:32:23

и
2
123455.jpg
abrgpro
NULL
2017-07-20 10:11:03

1-id 2- имя, 3-пользователь заливший, 4- рейтинг(пока пусто) 4-date(timestamp)

Comment: А вак как вообще вывести надо? 2017-07-20 09:32:23?

Comment: Желательно да, но при этом предварительно отконвертировав дату в формат часового пояса пользователя. Иными словами у меня UTC+3 поэтому для меня оно должно отображаться как 2017-07-20 11:32:23
Вывести получилось при помощи DATE_FORMAT(date, "%H %i "), и foreach ($stmt[0] as &$value) {
    echo"$value[0]";
    echo"$value[1]"; и так далее. Но в таком случае при $value[1]=$value[1]+3; значение становится равно 1 вместо 11 ($value[0] = 0 $value[1]=9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($result['date']));
//H:i:s - 24ти часовой формат
//h:i:s - 12х часовой формат
// strtotime - если не уверены в фомате поля date
```

**UPD:**

К вопросу часового пояса. Посмотрите, какой ч/п у вас по умолчанию на сервере (в php.ini)? Это можно сделать через *`phpinfo()`*, либо эхните *`date_default_timezone_get();`*. И если не ваш, то выставьте нужный (например для Украины) *`date_default_timezone_set('europe/kiev')`*

Comment: Выводит Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in, если использовать $result['date'][0] выводит 1970-01-01 12:00:00, если просто вывести echo $result['date']; выводит нормально 2017-07-20 09:32:23. Все еще не понятно почему не работает форматирование и как изменить часовой пояс.

Сейчас вся конструкция выглядит вот так:
`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM files where id=1';
                                          
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result['date'];`

Comment: Похоже что поле date  в таблице имеет текстовый тип а не дата/время. От того и неожиданный выхлоп. Поправил ответ под ваш вариант.

Comment: Действительно работает, однако тип таки дата/время [Скриншот](http://imgur.com/PahJAON). Большое спасибо за помощь. К сожалению не могу. Мой проект на бесплатном хостинге, поэтому и приходится мудрить с тем, что бы изменять часовой пояс путем скриптов уже после получения его с базы данных.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php тут и про таймзон и про ваш ворнинг.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо. Получилось решить свою проблему вот так  `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$date = new DateTime();
$date->getTimestamp();
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO files(name, user_name, date) VALUES (:name, :user_name, '$date')";` - код при добавлении файла. Осталось только придумать как получить временную зону пользователя и засунуть ее в date_default_timezone_set.